# How to solve this error: odoo.http.SessionExpiredException?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm trying to call odoo apis from my Node.js project. But the issue is session timeout error.

I'm following the below steps, please let me know where am I going wrong?

```
1. localhost:8069/web/session/authenticate
```

output in header: `Set-Cookie: session_id=558883b8c51a85d9dd1bb1f2ff10bc9b1cdc3ddd; Expires=Wed, 25-Jan-2023 11:35:54 GMT;`

```
  2. Sending the session_id in header for next requests as

headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Connection':'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' }
```

But it giving me the below error:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{
"code":100,"message":"Odoo Session Expired",
"data":{"name":"odoo.http.SessionExpiredException",
"debug":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File 
\"/opt/odoo/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py\", line 450, in _dispatch\n    cls._authenticate(func)\n  File \"/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py\", line 127, in _authenticate\n    getattr(cls, \"_auth_method_%s\" % auth_method)()\n  File \"/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py\", line 97, in _auth_method_user\n    raise http.SessionExpiredException(\"Session expired\")\nException\n\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py\", line 639, in _handle_exception\n    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File \"/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py\", line 315, in _handle_exception\n    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause\nodoo.http.SessionExpiredException: Session expired\n",
"message":"Session expired","arguments":["Session expired"],"context":{}}}}
```

But if I'm sending request to localhost:8069/web/session/authenticate from POSTMAN, and after that directly calling another odoo api then it gives me the expected result.

I didn't understand what params are sent by POSTMAN request, so that the session is valid for all other requests.

I was trying implement in django but same issue was there. Else in every request you have to pass dbname, password, username.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to installed module in existing database and it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check using the `uid` that your login (username and password) are correct. odoo returns a session_id even if your login is incorrect

**Correct login response**

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "result": {
        "session_id": "bd892d27ee2377f9129188987b697f09524d0bfe",
        "uid": 1,   <======= Returns the user id if authorized
        "is_system": true,
        "is_superuser": true,
        "user_context": {
            "lang": "en_US",
            "tz": "Europe/Brussels",
            "uid": 1
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**Incorrect login response**

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "result": {
        "session_id": "bd892d27ee2377f9129188987b697f09524d0bfe",
        "uid": false,
        "is_system": false,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "user_context": {},
        ...
    }
}
```